# condition sentences

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Although there are some concerns of increase in the usage of digital media, which are required to be addressed, but if I'm to choose between the print media or soft media, I'll vote for the digital media

We have an example of complex structure. Is it correct to use if after but? Also, I'm using although as an adverb? Is it correct

Regards;

Answer (score -1):

You are using two words that contradict your first phrase: *although* and *but*. This is incorrect. Your first phrase says that there are some concerns about digital media that need to be addressed. You can say

```
Although there are some concerns about an increase in the use of digital media,
which need to be addressed, if I'm to choose between print media or digital media,
I'll vote for digital media.
```

Or

```
There are some concerns about an increase in the use of digital media, which need 
to be addressed, but if I'm to choose between print media or digital media, I'll 
vote for digital media.
```

It is perfectly acceptable to use "if" after "but." However, "although" is not an adverb; it is a *conjunction*. "But" is also a conjunction. Conjunctions join two separate phrases, such as
"The tea is nice, **but** it needs sugar."
"We could go this way, **or** we could go that way."
"**Although** the weather is nice right now, it might rain later."